# What are the dangers of not handling 404 in a view?

Tags: django, django-views

The docs teach us that we must always provide django with either a `HttpResponse` or have an exception raised. As I'm coding a relatively small project, I am choosing to ignore proper `404` handling when writing a view, instead making sure that my data exists beforehand so that I don't even run into any `404`s.

Of course, this is obviously rather haphazard writing, and so to provide context to how I should actually be making these decisions - how does not properly handling `404`s in writing views affect things? For instance, will my website explode?

[edit]
So, for instance, I would use `my_stuff = Thing.objects_all()` instead of `my_stuff = get_object_or_404(Thing, pk=thing_id)`. Here, I already know that `Thing` has objects in it because I created them earlier in my admin, and they won't be removed. So, do I even need to worry about the `404`?

Comment: So, you're gonna handle every possible URL in the world, without ever returning a "not found"...?  What are you, Google?  The Wayback Machine?  :)

Comment: Yeah, agreed with previous commenter. Always assume the best and prepare for the worst. Proper usage of 404, 500 and whatnot will make you happy in the long run.

Comment: Well, it is a good philosophy to handle everything before hand, but Software always has bugs which we oversee. That is the reason we have 404 and 500. Lets say you have come up with this foolproof software which checks every data condition before hand, what happens if the user types something like: `mydomain.com/abcd` where `abcd` is not a valid URL ? So it is a good idea to have it in there.

Comment: Can you post an example of what you are doing, in your code? do your views result in `500` errors if resources aren't found?

Comment: cHao & limelights, your comments are not constructive, to me at least. The kind of information I would find much more valuable would tell me precisely (or at least give an idea of (other than general happiness)) why I would want to or would not want to include that code, as well as explain their consequences.

Comment: the first 3 comments tell you exactly why, and really are constructive. `assume the best, prepare for the worse` is WHY you want to handle such cases. your software may be perfect, but rely on some external api. your data may be perfect, but there's still some users interacting with it at some point. your database may die. your app may corrupt everything you thought was perfect. zombies may eat your data. don't rely on your data, don't rely on yourself. that's why :)